# Hive load CSV: load part of columns (or column mapping)

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, hive, bulkloader, bulk-load

I have CSV file with 20 columns but I need only three of them.

Is is possible to load part of columns? Something like column mapping during the bulk load in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sadly, if you want to use hive directly to load liek that it's impossible. Maybe try to use Java with MapReduce or an ETL like Talend